# Where can I place the code for redirecting 404 page in the PHP page?

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

I got the proper code for redirecting the 404 error if page not found during redirection but don't know where to apply this code in php file like in which tag of my php home page?
because when I'm going to place it i=on top so it directly show 404.php page and if i place it into html it show me tag error

```
<?php
http_response_code(404);
include('404.php');
die();
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense, likely based on a poor translation to English. If a page is not found during redirection, the web server will display a 404 error. You don't need to do anything. If you want a custom 404 page, you set that in the web server's settings (commonly in .htaccess). What you are doing is commonly used when PHP can't find content to include in a page.

Comment: im just fresher i want to do this operation for my new project in that if i want to check  about-us.php and if that page is not exists in project so it should be open 404.php page but i don't know where to set tha php code in html tags

Comment: You do not use PHP for what you are trying to do. You set the error page in your web server's settings, commonly in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly server adding a 404 page for not found pages in `.shtml` or `.html` you beter edit that file 
And Add this code to your htaccess file:

`ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php` or `.shtml` or `.html`

Comment: its not live project its on my localhost 

<html>
    <body>
          <a href="1.php">go</a>
          <a href="2.php">stop</a>
    </body>
</html>

in this code where can i place above code for 404 page redirection?

Comment: No, not in php files, create a new file in main directory and name it to `.htaccess` and add the code given in answer, in to htaccess, or search for htaccess tutorial on google

Answer (score 0):

With a single line in .htaccess you can redirect user to your 404 page

add this line to your .htaccess file
ErrorDocument 404 http://YOUR-PATH/404.php